# GLConsumer is already attached to a context for new SurfaceTexture

Tags: android, opengl-es, textureview

Is `SurfaceTexture` attached to `GLContext` by default when created manually? If so, how?

Here is an example, I'm trying to create my own `SurfaceTexture` and set it to `TextureView`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.version);
        TextureView textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);

        int[] arr = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, arr, 0);
        int texName = arr[1];

        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texName);
        textureView.setSurfaceTexture(surfaceTexture);
    }
}
```

I'm constantly getting:

> E/GLConsumer: [unnamed-29058-0] attachToContext: GLConsumer is already
>   attached to a context

And the exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: com.example.dkarmazin.openglesversion, PID: 29058
>                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during attachToGLContext (see logcat
>   for details)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.attachToGLContext(SurfaceTexture.java:215)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.GLES20TextureLayer.setSurfaceTexture(GLES20TextureLayer.java:86)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.setSurfaceTexture(HardwareRenderer.java:2228)
>                                                                                              at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:401)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13443)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13519)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14297)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3115)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2952)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13472)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13519)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14297)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3115)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2952)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14583)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13477)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13519)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14297)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3115)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2952)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14583)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13477)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13519)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14297)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3115)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2952)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13472)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13519)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14297)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3115)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2952)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13472)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13519)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14297)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3115)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2952)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14583)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13477)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13519)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1577)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2402)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1079)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5948)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Calling `detachFromGLContext` on newly created `SurfaceTexture` object solves the problem, but that's rather confusing as I can confirm that `attachToGLContext` is never called in this scenario.

P.S. I know that `TextureView` has it's own `SurfaceTexture` by default. In this scenario I have to use own implementation that extends from `SurfaceTexture`.

Answer (score 4):

I'll post an answer to my own question just in case someone else is facing the same issue.

Presumably, a new SurfaceTexture is attached to GLContext by default due to:

1. SurfaceTexture constructor calls to nativeInit
2. nativeInit corresponds to SurfaceTexture_init: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/core/jni/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.cpp#337
3. SurfaceTexture_init creates a new GLConsumer here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/core/jni/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.cpp#239

Solution would be to manually detach this newly created SurfaceTexture
from GLContext right after the call to a super constructor.

```
public class MySurfaceTexture extends SurfaceTexture {
    public MySurfaceTexture(int texName) {
        super(texName);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        super.detachFromGLContext();
    }
}
```

I looked up docs specifically for API-19, but you can follow the same path for other API levels.

Answer (score 3):

In Android O there is a [new constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#SurfaceTexture(boolean)) which doesn't attach immediately. Sounds like that's what you want. As your self-answer says, the previous constructors automatically attach to the current thread's GL context.